# Using strcpy with a char to a string?

Tags: c++

I couldn't figure out how to have an input with spaces stored in a string so I store it in a char first and I want to copy it to the string.

```
string name[2]={"Sample name"};
char apname[50];

cout << "Input Name: ";
cin.getline(apname,sizeof(apname));
strcpy (apname,name[2]);
```

If there's an easier way to do this please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::cout << "You said: " << line << "\n";
```

With error checking, prompting, and repetition, it'd be:

```
for (std::string line;
     (std::cout << "Input name: ") && std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::cout << "You said: " << line << "\n";
}
std::cout << "Goodbye\n";
```

Comment: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/In0jk2ZlxJ3dOIQl)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to operator `<<` which skips whitespace C++ Standard Library provides [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function overload for strings. Use it instead:

```
std::string name;
std::getline(cin, name);
```

Your function that calls

```
strcpy(apname, name[2]);
```

is incorrect for several reasons:

- You cannot copy characters directly into a `string`
- `name[2]` on an array of two items is referencing an item past the end of the array.